# How to do a serial execution on rxSwift variable?

Tags: ios, swift, observable, rx-swift

Consider the following two variables:

```
let int = Variable<Int>(1)

let string = Variable<String>("hey!")
```

let's assume that they are all bound to some UI already, like:

```
int.asObservable.bind(to:variable1)
string.asObservable.bind(to:variable2)
```

How can I make sure that `string.asObservable.bind(to:variable2)` is only executed after `int.asObservable.bind(to:variable1)` has been executed?

Comment: Are you sure by design than the 2 values will be updated every time ?

Comment: @CZ54 what do you mean?

Comment: every change of int will be followed by a change of string ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `int` and `string` are two different `variables`. It means that each variable can be changed independently.

You can join them to be sure that these values are changed simultaneously and delay the 2nd binding this way:

```
let values = Variable<(int: Int, string: String)>((1, "hey!"))
values
    .asObservable()
    .map({ $0.int })
    .bind(to: variable1)
values
    .asObservable()
    .map({ $0.string })
    .delay(0.1, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    .bind(to: variable2)
```